# CSS columns sitemap navigation

Tags: css

I want to have a sitemap in the footer of my page that has a limit for a height and arranges the links as in the image below. The site is CMS so this must be flexible. Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: CSS Columns]

Comment: This kind of vertical layout is really hard. You would have to use javascript, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can used For this, you can use the **column-count property:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="multicolumn1">
<div class="child">Link 1</div>
<div class="child">Link 2</div>
<div class="child">Link 3</div>
<div class="child">Link 4</div>
<div class="child">Link 5</div>
<div class="child">Link 6</div>
<div class="child">Link 7</div>
<div class="child">Link 8</div>
<div class="child">Link 9</div>
 <div class="child">Link 10</div>
 <div class="child">Link 11</div>
 <div class="child">Link 12</div>
```

**Css**

```
div#multicolumn1{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 33%;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 33%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 33%;
}
.child{
    height:20px;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/pMbtk/397/

Note: It does not work in IE.

For IE, you can use this JavaScript: CSS3 - [Multi Column Layout Demonstration](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/)